# WARN: Variable cannot be bound (it either doesn't exist or has been optimized away)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opengl-4

I am trying to pass a variable timeVar (a float initially set to 0.0) that changes in my display() method with the line

```
timeVar = time(0);
```

to my fragment shader. Then I do this

```
safe_glUniform1f(h_uTime, timeVar);
```

and pass it to my shader program like so

```
h_uTime = safe_glGetAttribLocation(h_program, "uTime");
```

But I keep getting this error. Please help!

```
WARN: uTime cannot be bound (it either doesn't exist or has been optimized 
away). safe_glAttrib calls will silently ignore it.
```

Comment: `uTime` seems to be a uniform but you query an attribute location. Try using `glGetUniformLocation` instead.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `uTime` is a uniform and not an attribute, using `glGetAttribLocation` will always result in an error. One has to use `glGetUniformLocation` instead.